# Not reading 2nd element of vector

Tags: r

I have this function

```
craps <- function() {
  one_game <- function() {
    firstroll <- sum(floor(runif(1,1,6)),floor(runif(1,1,6)))
    tosses <- 1
    if (firstroll %in% c(7, 11)) {
      return(c(win = 1, tosses = 1))
    }
    if (firstroll %in% c(2, 3, 12)) {
      return(c(win = 0, tosses = 1))
    }
    repeat {
      tosses = tosses + 1
      roll <-  sum(floor(runif(1,1,6)),floor(runif(1,1,6)))
      if (roll == firstroll) {
        return(c(win = 1,  tosses = tosses))
      }
      if (roll == 7) {
        return(c(win = 0, tosses = tosses))
      }
    }
  }
  WinsToss <- c(rowSums(replicate(x, one_game()))))
}
mean(WinsToss[1])
mean(winsToss[2])
```

I want to  to return the mean of random values drawn for that particular simulation.

But I get this error:

```
> mean(winsToss[2])
Error in mean(winsToss[2]) : object 'winsToss' not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your results are saved in craps. Try mean(craps[2]) (if you already executed the function).

Comment: Error in craps[2] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Well... it looks like your results are not in a vector, maybe a list... craps[[2]]? Try str(craps) to get more information about the structure of the data.

Comment: Typo... it's `WinsToss`, not `winsToss`